# "Begin size 0 is not equal to fixed size 5" Error in JMeter while generating HTML

Tags: jmeter

I need to generate a HTML file with JMeter 5.4.1 and when I press "Generate", I get

```
Error generating the report: org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.GenerationException: Error while processing samples: Consumer failed with message :Begin size 0 is not equal to fixed size 5
```

My user.properties is:

```
jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.property.output_dir=/Users/ivaneresko/Desktop
jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter=^(Search|Order)(-success|-failure)?$
jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.filters_only_sample_series=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true
```

What could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

After putting

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.report" level="debug" />
```

into *log4j2.xml* file I get this in the *jmeter.log* file:

```
2021-09-08 20:31:00,375 INFO o.a.j.g.a.HtmlReportGenerator: The HTML report generation failed and returned: An error occurred: Error while processing samples: Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Begin size 0 is not equal to fixed size 5
```

Doesn't say too much though.

This is my attached `output.jtl` file
[output.jtl](https://file.io/MvA9q8xc0UdD)

Comment: I am getting the same issue with a fresh install of jmeter 5.4.1 on windows

Comment: Downgraded JMeter to 5.2.14 with the same Java version and it works fine. It seems that it is something wrong with 5.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is likely due to an incompatibility of JMeter with Java 17. Whilst we wait for a fix, a workaround would be downgrading to Java 16.

Comment: Also doesn't work on Java 18

Answer (score 0):

The error is too generic and doesn't tell us a lot, I cannot reproduce it with your *user.properties* file on a fresh JMeter 5.4.1 instance.

As the minimum you need to add your [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) contents preferably with [debug logging enabled for the dashboard generation packages](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging), it can be done by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.report" level="debug" />
```

Ideally we need to see at least first 2 lines of your [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) (or better the full file) so we could reproduce the issue and state where the problem lives.

Answer (score 0):

It's happens cause in Java 17 stream.toArray() throwing exception when consumer initial array size is bigger than stream size. For example:

```
RankInfo[] topContentsRankPlayers = playersSorted.stream().limit(30).map(player -> new RankInfo(contentsType, player)).toArray(size -> new RankInfo[30]);
```

throws

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Begin size 0 is not equal to fixed size 30
```

if stream is empty